# The name of the theorem expressing the derivative of an integral with variable limits

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

What is the name of this theorem, or how to prove this?

$f(x)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{\Delta x}\int_{x-\frac{\Delta x}{2}}^{x+\frac{\Delta x}{2}}h(\xi)d\xi$

$\Longrightarrow$

$f'(x)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{\Delta x}\left\{h(x+\frac{\Delta x}{2})-h(x-\frac{\Delta x}{2})\right\}$

Comment: People call it the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leibniz Integral Rule

see here:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeibnizIntegralRule.html